# Can I bind multiple key shortcuts to the same action?

Tags: keyboard

I do a lot of pair programming. Some developers that I pair with use Linux as their primary desktop. So none of the keyboard shortcuts they are used to work.

What I would like to be able to do is bind multiple key chords to the same action. For example I want both ctrl-t and cmd-t to open a new tab in chrome.

I know that you can rebind shortcuts in system preferences/keyboard. I just don't know how to set multiple keystrokes to the same action.

Comment: Sorry Peter you're right, I deleted the answer as I misunderstood what the program did.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like adding a shortcut in the Keyboard preferences will override the built-in defaults. You can use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) (a paid app) to add such things - easiest would be to add a trigger for the alternative combo which translates into a menu action or into the original keyboard shortcut being sent to the application of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
probably not as powerful as Maestro, but for simple needs it does the job beautifully.

Comment: side note... this answer didn't work for me but if it did for you I'd be glad to hear that!
https://superuser.com/a/1204037/783618

Answer (score 0):

I use BetterTouchTool for this. Here you can create a keyboard shortcut which sends a shortcut of your choice. Simply as that!